# Where can I find a better version of this image?

Tags: icon, vector

I saw a hard copy of the symbol in the *lower left corner* of [this image](http://www.easyvectors.com/assets/images/vectors/source1/hand-hazard-symbols1.jpg) and I'm trying to find either a higher resolution version or a vector graphics version. I need something that will look good when sized to fill a coffee mug.

[image]

Alternatively, does anyone know what the name for that symbol is so I can do the search for myself?

---

BTW: I don't have much at all in the way of tools for this. As a result, the cost of solutions that involve more than downloading a file (e.g. removing the other hands from that image) will include the code of finding, installing and learning any needed software. I'm willing to spend some effort if need be, but I have more patience than free time.

Comment: Converting this kind of image to vector is dead easy in [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) (free, open source vector image editor), which can automatically trace bitmaps to editable vector images using [Potrace](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Potrace).

Answer (score 7):

I'm a big fan of importing images into Illustrator and tracing them. Those are all pretty clean lines, so creating a vector version wouldn't be all that hard.

Comment: I agree: this is a ridonkulously easy image to reverse engineer. Ideal for a little self-serve education.

Answer (score 6):

Try this site http://www.bazaardesigns.com/3837-hand-hazard-symbols/ or do a search for "hands hazard symbol" in Bing or Google.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the exact graphic from the question *is* a vector file on that site, so the particular item can simple be copied out of it into a separate file.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/) when searching for the origin of shrunken images. I didn't get an exact match for yours, but maybe by cropping what you are looking for you will have some better luck.