# How to find the source of a stock photo?

Tags: stock-images

I have the following screen shot of an image. How can I find the original? I believe it may have come from Getty Images. I'd like to purchase the original version of this, but don't know where to find it.

[image]

Comment: The file name may give you a clue.

Comment: i had to crop it out of a jpeg.  The jpeg was called OPC.PNG (it was renamed so i don't know the oriignal filename)

Comment: Yes, seen similar on istock or dreamstime. Not certain why my spending time looking for it is any better than you spending your time.

Comment: Edited to make the question a little more general...we didn't really have a direct question on here that could be answered with "TinEye"! (Apart from http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2315/5489 but I thought that was different enough to not vote to close this as a duplicate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you think it came from Getty, send them a message and see if they can dig it up for you. They'll be happy to do a little image research if they know you're going to pay.

Answer (score 6):

Cool product called [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/) will do this reverse image lookup for you. Results vary depending on the source image, of course, but it could save you a bit of time.

Comment: There's also Google Reverse Image Search (do a normal google image search, then click the camera icon in the input box and upload your image): tineye usually gets more accurate results, but it sometimes finds things TinEye doesn't. Not sure how good either is at *parts* of a whole image though - in google image reverse, selecting 'Visually similar' may help.

Comment: ooh, google does that too? The things you learn. :)

Comment: Both google images and tineye are such useful tools!  Thanks a lot guys!